# Automatically clear cache in browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web, browser

I am wondering if it's possible to enable automatic clearing of cache in browser when the application is accessed? The thing is that sometimes when the user accessed the newly published asp.net mvc site in their browser they need to clear their browser cache to see the new site since the previous version of the site is the one that reflects in their browser. I have no idea about the right approach to do this. Can someone please shed some light? Thank you a bunch !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right approach is to have [Cache Busting](https://madskristensen.net/post/cache-busting-in-aspnet) implemented in your website.

> Cache busting is the process of appending some form of file version
>   hash to the filename of resources like JavaScript and CSS files

It will automatically take care of cache to get performance (if file is not changed) and will not allow the cache if file is changed.

If you use [bundling and minification in asp.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) ,then also this will be taken care for you.

asp.net bundling creates url contains a query string pair like  `v=r0sLDicvP58AIXN_mc3QdyVvVj5euZNzdsa2N1PKvb81`

> The query string v has a value token that is a unique identifier used
>   for caching. As long as the bundle doesn't change, the ASP.NET
>   application will request the AllMyScripts bundle using this token. If
>   any file in the bundle changes, the ASP.NET optimization framework
>   will generate a new token, guaranteeing that browser requests for the
>   bundle will get the latest bundle

Answer (score 1):

when you say clear cache I am assuming you mean `js` and `css` files

If so, one way to do it is when need refresh, give it a different url

This can be achieve by appending a version number in querystring such as:

```
my.js?v=1.0
```

so when it is updated to v2 change it to

```
my.js?v=2.0
```

and my.js will be updated

same for css file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
 // Stop Caching in IE
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);

// Stop Caching in Firefox
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

[This might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963273/refresh-browser-cache-automatically)