# File A replaced on server with B but File A is displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've run into a problem in a situation where an image is deleted and another file with the same name is saved in its stead (i.e. the file is replaced). As shown below:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult _ReplaceGeneral(int ID, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
     var dbpath = query.FindImages(ID);
     var path = Server.MapPath(dbpath.ImageURL);

     System.IO.File.Delete(path);
     file.SaveAs(path);

     TempData["Message"] = "Image Successfully Replaced!";

     return RedirectToAction("EditGallery");
}
```

In my server the file is successfully replaced. However, when I launch the site, the previous image is displayed.

*Notes:*

- The Image isn't saved in my database- it's saved on my Server and the URL is stored on the database.
- I can physically see the file replaced in the server so I'm absolutely positive it's being replaced.

**Question:** How and why does Image A display on my website even after replacing it with Image B?

I haven't been able to find any resources that articulate why and how this issue occurs so I apologize if it's a duplicate.

Comment: How are you using that image in the website?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya There are two ways I understand the questions 1. The Images are stored in a folder on my Server. The Database stores the URLs of these photos. 2. It's used both in the CSS as a `background-image = "relative path"` and the `<img src=@Url.Content()>` tag

Comment: It sounds like the browser is caching the image and, as the name hasn't changed, just loads it from cache.

Comment: @Diado I just tried clearing all my browser data and I can confirm that  the image does change when I do so. How can I workaround this issue?

Comment: If images are being saved successfully then caching could be the only issue. Once the image is saved, and if you refresh the page in browser by pressing Ctrl+F5, does it show the new image?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, any workarounds you can suggest?

Comment: Some hint at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963273/refresh-browser-cache-automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a browser caching issue. If the URL of the image does not change the browser will use the cached version and not fetch the image from the server.

You can get round this by getting the image files last modified date/time convert that to a number and add it to the image URL as a query string (e.g. &t=XXXXX). In this way when the image file changes the URL changes too. The browser will then load the new image.

Comment: Say I need to use the relative path for a CSS background-image. The suggested workaround will not work as the `background-image: url("")` wouldn't change. Is there any other workarounds we can use?

Comment: Add the `background-image` in a style attribute in the HTML or modify the CSS when the image is modified (add a querystring to the CSS reference to ensure it is updated and not cached).

Comment: I know it's a bit much to ask, but do you have any resources I can look at to help me construct your suggested workaround?